# Cargar información a SELECT OPTION con AJAX, PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Tengo un SELECT OPTION, en el cuál quiero que me aparezcan todos lo registros de una tabla, teniendo en cuenta que la tabla solo tiene los atributos el id (que ocuparé como el valor) y Nombre (que se mostrará).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

formuario.php es en donde tengo el formulario y donde va el ajax.

```
<form class="text-center border border-light p-5 needs-validation" name="formCreate" id="formCreate" novalidate>
<!-- select option COMPANY -->
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="md-form md-outline">
                    <select id="sCompany" name="sCompany" class="form-control search-select">
                        <!-- <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Company...</option>
                        <option value="1">Windows</option>
                        <option value="2">iOS</option>
                        <option value="3">Android</option>
                        <option value="4">iPhone</option>
                        <option value="5">Nexus</option>  -->
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
...
```

Este es mi intento de código ajax para realizar lo que deseo.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
//SELECT OPTION COMPANY
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "controller/select_option.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            //console.log(response);
            $('#sCompany').html(response);
            console.log(response);
            console.log(1);
            // for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            //     $("#sCompany").append(
            //         '<option value='response['idCompany']'>'response['Name']'</option>';
            //     )
            // }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Este es mi código **select_option.php**

```
<?php
include "../../../session/conexion.php"; //Conexion
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); //Abre una conexión al Servidor de MySQL que está en ejecución.
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8"); //Establece el conjunto de caracteres del cliente

// CONSULTA COMPAÑIAS
$sql = "SELECT * FROM company";

$datos = $mysqli->query($sql);
// while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos)) {

// }
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($datos)) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row["idCompany"] . '">' . $row["Name"] . '</option>';
}
echo json_encode();//no sé qué debe ir aquí o sí es correcto
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

No sé como regresar la información al cliente y del cliente asignarlo al SELECT OPTION

Gracias por su tiempo, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme a comprender mejor!

Comment: En teoría, basta con que en _PHP_ quites `echo json_encode();`, porque ya estás creando el HTML para llenar el _select_ y dejar _Javascript_ sin modificaciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes añadir elementos option en un select utilizando  `$('#sCompany').html(response);`  para poder añadir las opciones al select deberías de hacer que el php devolviera la array de todos los registros  `json_encode(mysqli_fetch_array($datos));` luego recorrer el array con un `forEach()` en el ajax y añadir cada option al select  `$("#sCompany").append(new Option("Nombre", "Id"));`